# How to do a mapview showing your current location that is similar to google maps?

Tags: android

Is there anyway to do a similar type? as in a map show the current direction of the user and where he is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `MyLocationOverlay` to the `MapView`:

```
me=new MyLocationOverlay(this, map);
map.getOverlays().add(me);
```

It will show the user's location (if you have the proper permissions) and it will show the user's orientation via a compass rose (if you run it on a device with the right sensors). You can see this, along with a custom overlay, in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk).